# R List Store as string

Tags: r, list

I have the following list containing strings:

```
"list(name = c(\"Marca\", \"CondiciÃ³n del Ã­tem\", \"Modelo\"), 
     value_id = c(NA, \"2230284\", NA))"
```

How can I tell R to understand that string as a list?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An option is to `eval`uate

```
eval(parse(text= str1))
#$name
#[1] "Marca"                "CondiciÃ³n del Ã­tem" "Modelo"              

#$value_id
#[1] NA        "2230284" NA
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "list(name = c(\"Marca\", \"CondiciÃ³n del Ã­tem\", \"Modelo\"), value_id = c(NA, \"2230284\", NA))"
```